# Qual Script SQL em Postgres para retornar os campos que pertecem a PK?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Qual Script SQL em Postgres para retornar os campos que pertecem a chave primaria de uma tabela especifica do banco ?

Comment: Pessoal eu só coloquei dicar de como Obter essa informação, não é pergunta..  eu pesquiso muito e só acho no stack em ingles..e por isso estou colocando scripts mais simplificados para pessoas que estao aparendendo...  obrigado..  ** não é necessário negativar...** podem reparar que fui eu mesmo que respondi

Comment: Mas você pode colocar isso como pergunta. Coloque editando a sua pergunta por exemplo:  Qual é o *comando* `SQL` para trazer de uma tabela no banco PostGreSQL qual é o campo configurado como chave primária (`primary key`). O que você fez é válido é que você fez errado, não pode ser uma constatação mas, sim um pergunta realmente.

Comment: A ta eu tinha feito como pergunta e negativaram tambem.. pensei que tinha sido porque tinha colocado como pergunta...    vou editar...   obrigado

Comment: Gustavao é pergunta e resposta no site, então se faz uma pergunta e pode até responde-lá sem problemas. Na resposta explique melhor também de um contexto, fale sobre o assunto, etc etc etc ... !

Comment: Referencias Gustavo acho eu que enriquece também mais a pergunta e/ou respostas

Answer (score 1):

Nas minhas pesquisas encontrei várias maneiras de se fazer esse script, quero mostrar aqui uma maneira bem simples de como retornar esses dados, isso para ajudar as pessoas que estão iniciando

```
 select kcu.table_schema,
           kcu.table_name,
           tco.constraint_name,
           kcu.ordinal_position as position,
           kcu.column_name as key_column
    from information_schema.table_constraints tco
    join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
         on kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
         and kcu.constraint_schema = tco.constraint_schema
         and kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
    where tco.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' and 
           kcu.table_name = 'sua_tabela'
    order by kcu.table_schema,
             kcu.table_name,
             position;
```